# Error when creating instance of a class

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm trying to assign an arrayList a instance of a class but it is giving me the following error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is my code that assigns it.

```
Public memberList As ArrayList

Public Sub LoadUser()
Dim userId As Integer = 0
    Dim userData As Data.DataTable = oExecuteSimpleQuery_DT("QA", "SELECT * FROM Member")
    If userData IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each user As Data.DataRow In userData.Rows
            If memberList(userId) Is Nothing Then
                memberList(userId) = 1
            End If
            memberList(userId) = New clsMember(user("UserID"), user("Firstname"), user("Secondname"), user("Username"), user("Password"), user("Email"), user("Rights"))
            userId += 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code shown in your question you do declare the `memberList` variable, but you do not create an instance. In order to solve the error, change the first line to:

```
Public memberList As New ArrayList()
```

Two side nodes:

- Instead of using `ArrayList`, have a look at [`List(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It offers almost the same functionality, but is strongly typed.
- A `NullReferenceException` is a common error that is worth understanding. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for details on the reasons and on how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Public memberList as New List(Of clsMember)


Public Sub LoadUser()
 Dim userId As Integer = 1
 Dim userData As Data.DataTable = oExecuteSimpleQuery_DT("QA", "SELECT * FROM Member")
 If userData IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each user As Data.DataRow In userData.Rows
        memberList.Add(New clsMember(user("UserID"), user("Firstname"), user("Secondname"), user("Username"), user("Password"), user("Email"), user("Rights"))
        userId += 1
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks seems to have worked although now another error is appearing 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: Your index out of range is being caused by the data rows that uou are looping through.  If its a grid (and I suspect it is) then the rows are numbered from 0 not 1 (you need to take account of the header row). So loop through the grid (ie for index as integer = 0 to <gridname.rows.count> [do you processing here] next.  That should solve that problem